# How can I change the theme of Application in Android?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-theme

I am developing an android application.
I want to add a feature to let the user to change the application's theme at the runtime.

I try to use the following statement in my main activity.

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black);
```

However, it merely change the dialog to black background with white text.

What can I do to change all the componenets' theme to Black including the action bar and fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a global runtime change, what could work is extending [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) and setting the theme (probably in [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29), since this class also has a [`setTheme()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) method on account of it extending `ContextWrapper`.

Make sure to declare your Application class in the manifest:

```
<application
        android:name="com.yourpackage.ApplicationClass" >
</application>
```

However, since extending application is usually frowned upon, I'd rather set the theme on a per `Activity` basis since Activities get destroyed and recreated way more often than the `Application` object. Maybe make a static method that returns the current theme from `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Theme_Holo` instead of `Theme_Black`, keep in mind that you need to create your own theme if you want everything to be turn black.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading into the Styles and Themes section of the developer docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

You can do a lot of theming from your manifest by using things such as:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Dark">
```